# Why is the bar construction of a DG algebra a coalgebra?

Tags: differential-graded-algebras

Let $A$ be a differentially graded augmented algebra. Then $\mathbf{B}A$ can be equipped with the structure of a coalgebra. This is proved in, for example, Loday and Vallette's book on *Algebraic Operads.*

The $n$-lab page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bar+and+cobar+construction points out that the coalgebra structure can be understood as showing all the possible ways to decompose a path of length $n$ into pairs of shorter paths of lengths $(p,q)$ with $p+q=n$. This helps but I still don't really have intuition.

Many books *define* $\mathbf{B}A$ as follows. First, we can construct the free (conilpotent) coalgebra on $\mathbf{B}A$. Now, define the differential using the universal property of the free coalgebra, and check that it happens to satisfy the law $d^2=0$; so we have a DG coalgebra.

This makes sense, of course. However even if you had no idea that $\mathbf{B}A$ was supposed to be a coalgebra, there's still a very natural differential to put on that chain complex, which comes from applying the Moore normalization to the simplicial object constructed using this process. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/two-sided+bar+construction

So my question is, if I look at $\mathbf{B}A$ as the Moore normalization of the two-sided bar construction $B(1,A,1)$ (where $A$ acts on $1$ as a module on both the left and the right) why should we expect this to have a coalgebra structure. Or, alternatively, if you prefer to view $\mathbf{B}A$ as a coalgebra a priori on top of which we can put a unique compatible differential, why does this differential agree with the one given by $B(1,A,1)$?

I think I am either looking for geometric intuition for why this should be true, or ideally kind of nice categorical argument by which we can construct the comultiplication and counit on $B(1,A,1)$.